# Cannot easy_install readline for Python 2.7.3 on Mac Os Lion

Tags: python, osx-lion, readline, easy-install

I am trying to install the python readline module. I have already installed readline via homebrew.
If I type

```
easy_install readline
```

I get

```
Downloading http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/r/readline/readline-6.2.2.tar.gz#md5=ad9d4a5a3af37d31daf36ea917b08c77
Processing readline-6.2.2.tar.gz
Writing /var/folders/44/dhrdb5sx53s243j4w03063vh0000gn/T/easy_install-64FbG8/readline-6.2.2/setup.cfg
Running readline-6.2.2/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /var/folders/44/dhrdb5sx53s243j4w03063vh0000gn/T/easy_install-64FbG8/readline-6.2.2/egg-dist-tmp-NOmStB
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'readline/libreadline.a'
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'readline/libhistory.a'
error: Setup script exited with error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit status 1
```

Any ideas about how I could fix this ?

Thanks

Comment: D'oh, sorry, didn't notice the first line of your question. Ok, trying again.

Comment: Which version of Python are you using?

Comment: it's in the first line of the question, python 2.7.3 installed via homebrew

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try installing the binary egg directly:

```
$ easy_install http://pypi.python.org/packages/2.7/r/readline/readline-6.2.2-py2.7-macosx-10.7-intel.egg#md5=25383d860632d4a1521961ba68a52fe2
```

Comment: same error, but following your suggestion I tried

`easy_install http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/r/readline/readline-6.2.0.tar.gz`

to install a previous version, and it worked! Thanks!

Comment: easy_install of that old version didn't work for me... same error. :\ Any other tips?

Answer (score 15):

There is a new solution to this problem in Pypi, `pip install gnureadline`.

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/gnureadline

The root issue is libedit (BSD-licensed) vs. Gnu Readline (GPL-licensed) . Apple would rather provide incompatible BSD code, than provide compatible code that has GPL restrictions.

Comment: After this, what's the best way to use gnureadline if a script is on OS X but readline if it's run elsewhere? I have an awkward `try: import gnureadline as readline except ImportError: import readline` right now... it'd be nice to cut it down to a single import line...

Answer (score 4):

This bug should be fixed in readline version 6.2.4 released last week.

Also note that you do not need to install the readline library itself via homebrew. It is already included within the python readline module.

Anyone having problems with the python-readline module is welcome to open an issue on [the GitHub page](https://github.com/ludwigschwardt/python-readline) of the module. This will ensure that the problem is permanently solved for everyone.

Answer (score 2):

I had this same problem in OS X Lion 10.8, and fixed it by renaming my /Developer to /Developer-old. See [this issue](https://github.com/ludwigschwardt/python-gnureadline/pull/19).

Answer (score 1):

None of the above worked from me.
After uninstall ipython and readline, I ran the following that finally worked

```
easy_install http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/r/readline/readline-6.1.0.tar.gz
pip install ipython
```

And yes, readline 6.1.0 is an old one, but 6.2.x or other would not work (in sept 2013).

Comment: This worked for me on OS X 10.9.1 and Python 2.7.5. Inside a virtualenv. I didn't have to reinstall ipython for it to work properly.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have gcc installed.

```
which gcc
```

should return

```
/usr/bin/gcc
```

I was getting the same error when trying to easy_install readline. It wasn't until I downloaded the tar and tried to manually build it that I noticed it said

```
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... no
checking for gcc... no
checking for cc... no
checking for cl.exe... no
configure: error: in `/Users/roneill/readline-6.2.4.1/rl/readline-lib':
configure: error: no acceptable C compiler found in $PATH
See `config.log' for more details.
```

that I realized what the actual problem was. I had not used this particular laptop in a while and had not used Xcode to install the command line tools. Once I did, things worked properly.